# Частичное подключение стилей bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap

Ситуация следующая:
Я воспользовался компонентом из бутстрапа и мне нужно частично импортировать стили только лишь для этого компонента. Такое в теории возможно ?

В документации по подключению он мне предлагает глобально просто все стили подключить и все, но так не получится, так как у меня есть созвучное название классов и стили наложились на другой компонент и получилась беда.

Кто может что-нибудь посоветовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Устанавливаете SCSS (если не установили по какой-то причине), отключаете автоматическую загрузку css в настройках `bootstrap-vue` (`bootstrapVueCSS: false`), собираете bootstrap/bootstrap-vue как душе угодно.

Что делать:

1. Заходите в исходники (`~bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss`)
2. Видите нужные импорты и смотрите, что важно а что нет (`utilities` и `variables` скорее всего нужны для всего)
3. Идёте в компонентные импорты (`components/index`)
4. Импортите себе то, что нужно

Т.е файл примерно будет так выглядеть для подгрузки стилей только для компонента `BTime`:

```
@import "~bootstrap-vue/src/_variables";
@import "~bootstrap-vue/src/_utilities";

@import "~bootstrap-vue/src/components/time/index"
```

Учтите, что у `bootstrap-vue` не так много стилей, он зависит от `bootstrap`, у которого свои стили. Там тоже нужно отдельно SCSS пересобирать, если требуется (по инструкции из официальной документации Bootstrap можно, там описаны шаги, аналогичные выше).

---

Но вообще я бы Вам рекомендовал просто переименовать классы от именно ваших компонентов, если Вы не гонитесь за уменьшением размера бандла. Это банально проще.